# How to embed an HTML div inside of a svg

Tags: dom, svg

Example:

```
<div> Hello World </div>

<svg>
<div> From SVG Land</div>
</svg>
```

Question:

Despite the tags, are SVG objects parsed separately and not some proper part of the dom tree? How do I get DIVs inside of SVG elements?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by @Stasik, foreignObject can be used.

*Example:*

```
<svg>
    <foreignObject width="100" height="50"
               requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <!-- XHTML content goes here -->
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>
      </body>
    </foreignObject>
<svg>
```

*Extracted from:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject